# ERROR 18538 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter :

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-21T09:51:20.646+05:30 ERROR 18538 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field jdbcTemplate in com.snigdha.snigdhahospitals.controller required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your configuration.

I tried to run the springboot application after adding the JDBC and application failed to start

pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.1.3
 

com.snigdha
snigdhahospitals
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
snigdhahospitals
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>20</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-jdbc


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-webflux

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build> -->
```

controller.java

```
package com.snigdha.snigdhahospitals;

// import javax.swing.tree.RowMapper;

// import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
// import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
// import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
// import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
// import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
// import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
// import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
// import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
// import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
// import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.snigdha.snigdhahospitals.model.Doctor;

// import ch.qos.logback.core.model.Model;



@RestController
public class controller {


    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/d")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Doctor>> getDoctors(){
        List<Doctor> doctors = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM DOCTOR", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Doctor>(Doctor.class));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(doctors,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("home");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView homepage(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("home");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/doctors")
    public ModelAndView doctors(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("doctors");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("login");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/signup")
    public ModelAndView signup(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("signup");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/appointments")
    public ModelAndView appointments(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("appointments");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/contactus")
    public ModelAndView contactus(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("contactus");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/grievance")
    public ModelAndView grievance(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("grievance");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/aboutus")
    public ModelAndView aboutus(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("aboutus");
        return mv;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you added the Spring JDBC dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes , i have added jdbc in my pom.xml